# @Valid in Weblogic 10.3.6 not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, weblogic-10.x, hibernate-validator

I am trying to deploy the application in Weblogic 10.3.6, which is working good in Tomcat 8. I faced couple of issue and fixed, finally I am stuck with one error struggling since 2 days. Issue is with @Valid annotation. I am getting an exception as below.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isCascadeRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1277)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:152)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.1/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:index-directory-enabled>false</wls:index-directory-enabled>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.bootstrap.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.constraints.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.groups.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.metadata.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.ejb.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.validation.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.security.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.security.config.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.security.core.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.security.web.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.oxm.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.jms.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.jws.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.aop.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.aop.aspectj.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.web.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name> org.springframework.web.method.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.web.method.support.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.web.servlet.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name> org.springframework.aop.support.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:prefer-application-resources>
                <wls:resource-name>org.springframework.*</wls:resource-name>
                <wls:resource-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:resource-name>
                <wls:resource-name>javax.validation.*</wls:resource-name>
                <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:resource-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-resources>

        <!-- If the show-archived-real-path-enabled element is set to true, then the servlet container's getRealPath()
        for archived web applications will return the canonical path of the resource file otherwise it will be null-->

        <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>


    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: JPATraversableResolver has a call to Persistence.getPersistenceUtil(), which is suppose to go to javax.persistance, but it is taking me to org.apache.openjpa.persistence on weblogic

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a wrong/inconsistent JPA setup. The `javax.persistence` interface classes are not matching the implementation classes provided by `org.apache.openjpa`. See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-425.

This blog [post](https://prafullagupta.wordpress.com/tag/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-apache-openjpa-persistence-persistenceproviderimpl-getproviderutilljavaxpersistencespiproviderutil/) describes a workaround.

Comment: I am trying blog solution. But I am getting an exception " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl" when application loading

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Validator do you use? ConfigurationImpl has moved package during its lifetime. It used to be in org.hibernate.validator.engine

Comment: And Hibernate Version : 4.1.12.Final

Comment: Ok, in this version it should be org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl. Can you check your Validator jar file to see whether it contains this class. If so, you must have some classloader visibility issue.

Comment: I could not able to figure it out. Can you please guide me. Thank you

Comment: I changed Version of Hibernate 4.2.0, that fixed the issue, but facing other issue as "java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/validation/metadata/BeanDescriptor""

Comment: Finally I have fixed, thank you for your help. I will update my answer now.